# Copy a file to remote server using SSH

Tags: ssh

I want to backup a mysql database et copy it to a remote server.

I do :

```
mysqldump -uroot myDb>$HOME/myDb.sql && tar czf - $HOME/myDb.sql | ssh root@ip "dd of=$HOME/myDb_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).tar.gz" $HOME/backup/myDb
```

It doesn't work, I am getting :

```
dd: opérande «/home/backup/myDb» non reconnu
```

When I do

```
mysqldump -uroot myDb>$HOME/myDb.sql && tar czf - $HOME/myDb.sql | ssh root@ip "dd of=$HOME/myDb_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).tar.gz"
```

It works but I want to copy the file in folder on my remote server, not at the root folder.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please prepend `LC_ALL=C` to your commands so that we get error messages in English?

Comment: `mysqldump -u -p db | gzip | ssh user@host "cat > whatever.sql.gz"`

Answer (score 3):

Is this not easier?

```
d = $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
mysqldump -uroot myDb>$HOME/myDb.$d.sql 
tar czf - $HOME/myDb.$d.sql
scp $HOME/myDb.$d.sql root@ip:$HOME/backup/
```

The mistake in your command: the last part is seen as part of the `dd` command. Not as part of the `ssh` command.

===

regarding comments:

> the thing is that when the scp is performed it doesn"t know the exact name of the file because of the date/hour/second suffix.

That variable "d" does not change its contents over time:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ d=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ echo "$d"
20190427115534
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ echo "$d"
20190427115534
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ echo "$d"
20190427115534
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ echo "$d"
20190427115534
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ echo "$d"
20190427115534
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to suffix the file with date/hour/second before scp it.

Comment: so do that too ;-) 1 sec. There: set the date to a variable 1st so the variable stays the same and then re-apply it.

Comment: the thing is that when the scp is performed it doesn"t know the exact name of the file because of the date/hour/second suffix. So I cant scp it. The solution with the ssh works except that I don't know how to go in a particular folder in the remote server.

Comment: and that's why you create a variable. The value of "d" does NOT change. sorry but "scp"  is the command to copy files to another server.  I don't see how ssh can be better than the command that is suppose to do what you want.

Comment: You could also trivially solve it with `cat > file.I.want.tgz` (although creating a tgz of a single file is odd in and of itself)

Comment: thanks Rinzwind, could give the syntax if I run it in a single line (like in a cron taks per example). I am confused about how to do it.

Comment: eh. don't put those in cron. put the lines in a script and put the script in cron.

Comment: @thomas create a well named script and put that in cron. Otherwise there will come a day when you open your cronfile for some really urgent reason and you find you cannot remember what all your one-liners actually do.